# How to get POSTed (jquery) array data in Node.js (using express)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js

I am trying to post an array to my server. But I have difficulties in doing it properly.

The array I am trying to post, is an array of objects which is dynamically structured, thus I don't know it's length.

To be more precise, my array is of the form.

```
var names =[{id:1, name:"nick"},{id:2,name:"bob"},{id:3,name:"john"}.....{id:n, name:"whatever"}]
```

I am posting using jquery:

```
$.post("save_names", {
        'names[]': names
    }, function(results) {
        alert(results);
    });
```

My node code, is the following: (I use stormpath-express)

```
app.post('/save_names', config.access_group, function(req, res) {
    console.log("body ", req.body);
});
```

This way i am getting the following from the console.log

```
body  { 'names[]': [ '[object Object]', '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ] }
```

When i try to print the array : `console.log("body ", req.body.names);`
I get `body  undefined`

Can somebody explain why this is happening? How to solve my error, and why can't I just post names:names and simply work?

Comment: 2 things: set the jQuery post content-type to application/json, and set bodyParser in express middleware that can read json.
I suspect you're using regular www-form-urlencoded, and it can't do anything else but simple key-value.

Comment: @Zlatko, Could you give me an example?

Comment: Well, it's simple, client-side: `$.ajax({
  url:url,
  type:"POST",
  data:data,
  contentType:"application/json",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(){
    ...
  }
})`

And on express server, for example `app.use(bodyParser.json())` or whatever middleware you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending your data incorrectly. You can examine request in Development tools. You'll see something like this:

```
Form Data
    names[]:[object Object]
    names[]:[object Object]
    names[]:[object Object]
    names[]:[object Object]
```

Try converting data to JSON yourself:

```
$.post("save_names", {
        'names[]': JSON.stringify(names)
    }, function(results) {
        alert(results);
    });
```

Don't forget to correctly access your array: `console.log("body ", req.body['names[]']);`.

Comment: JSON.stringify is what i need. As the array is now passed as a string and not as an array the 'names[]' is no longer needed and can become just names. Then i can get the variable using, req.body.names. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you `req.body` contains key `names[]`, not `names`. So you can either grab from `req.body['names[]']` or rewrite code to have name object:

```
$.post("save_names", {
        names: names
    }, function(results) {
        alert(results);
    });
```

And express code:

```
app.post('/alter_offer_sort', config.access_group, function(req, res) {
    console.log("body ", req.body.names);
});
```

P.S. probably you grab `[]` names from a GET Query. It's not how POST works.

**UPDATE**:

I also don't notice, that there is just string of object, so initialize bodyParser.

First install body-parser:

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

Then modify code to this:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: Oh, I see. `[object Object]`. POST data isn't parsed as JSON.