# How to create append an array to a json value using (js/node/express)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to re-create a CRUD app in NodeJs that I did using php/mysql etc, that takes a users form information and stores it in a file called "sample-data.json".

Essentially, with NodeJs a user fills in a form, front-end JS takes that info, passes it along to an api route I set up, and then using FS, writes that info to the sample-data.json file etc.

With the code below, once a users hits submit on the form, the code takes that info, and passes it to the "sampledataapi" route.

```
$("#createTodoForm").submit(function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
    
            $.post("/sampledataapi",{
                todoCompany : $("#todoTitle").val(), 
                thisTodoIsFor : $("#todoIsFor").val(),  
                todoPostedBy : $("#todoPostedBy").val(), 
                todoCompleted : $("#todoCompleted").val(), 
                todoPriority : $("#todoPriority").val(), 
                todoMessages : $("#todoFirstMessage").val()
            }, showDataGotten );

        });
```

Once it saves the data, my sample-data.json file which initially has an empty array inside of it, then gets populated with info.

So sample-data.json goes from this: `[]`

To this(once data has been entered):

```
[
    {
        "todoCompany":"sample company",
        "thisTodoIsFor":"todo is for me",
        "todoPostedBy":"admin",
        "todoCompleted":"no",
        "todoPriority":"green",
        "todoMessages" : "sample message"
    }
]
```

Now when I do this, all works fine but I run into problems when I want to have "todoMessages" be an array from the get go. Reason is that once the user posts their data, they will have the ability to erase/add messages from that block.

So I need that when the user submits the data, instead of that "todoMessages" being a regular string, I want it to be like this:

```
"todoMessages" : [ "sample message" ]
```

This way, I can push info into it OR delete from it etc.
How can I make it so that when the user creates his data, and the data passes the info to the route/json file, that it automatically creates todoMessages as an array?

I have tried (on front end)

```
todoMessages : [$("#todoFirstMessage").val()]
```

but then the front end reads "undefined"
and the backend json has this:

```
"todoMessages[]":"sample message"
```

Comment: have you tried simply `todoMessages : [$("#todoFirstMessage").val()]` in the `$.post call` ?

Comment: ... and did it work ^^

Comment: Yep i have tried that but, what happens is that "todoMessages" turns into this ->  "todoMessages[] : "message entered here"

Comment: I believe that is the espected format for POST array data, but you'd expect the server at `"/sampledataapi"` to translate that into successive array values. What is on the server side ?

Comment: maybe the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30260353/161622 will point you in the right direction ?

Comment: Thanks, that definately did. The values come through now, and get placed in an array. Now i have to figure out how to remove all them funky characters like the brackets and quotes and all that but, for now its one step closer. Thank you

Comment: It was a step in the right direction but. It didnt solve the issue because the array comes through as a string(very close though so thank you). It came out like this: "todoMessages":"[\" sample text \"]". I need it to come out like this: "todoMessages": ["sample text"]